# Searching for a word pattern in a Python dataset

Tags: python, regex, string, count

I hope I'm able to explain this problem clearly. I'm a python experimenter (just in case the below query appears naive)

Assume that I have a dataset of the form:

```
a = ( ('309','308','308'), ('309','308','307'), ('308', '309','306', '304'))
```

Let me call each `('309','308','308')` as a path.

I want to find the count of:

a. `Count('309','308', <any word>)`

b. `Count('309',<any word>,'308')`

and all possible permutations.

I'm thinking its some kind of a regex which will help me achieve this search. And, the number of paths I have goes onto 50000.

Can anyone suggest how I can do this kind of an operation in python? I explored trie, radix but I dont think that'll help me.

Thanks,
Sagar

Comment: Were there meant to be four numbers in the last tuple?

Comment: yes.. it can be any number > 1..not 3 or 4 as in my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to do this:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = ( ('309','308','308'), ('309','308','307'), ('308', '309','306', '304'))
>>> Counter((x, y) for (x, y, *z) in a)
Counter({('309', '308'): 2, ('308', '309'): 1})
>>> Counter((x, z) for (x, y, z, *w) in a)
Counter({('308', '306'): 1, ('309', '308'): 1, ('309', '307'): 1})
```

I'm also using extended tuple unpacking here, which didn't exist pre-Python 3.x, which is only needed if you have tuples of an uncertain length. In python 2.x, you could instead do:

```
Counter((item[0], item[1]) for item in a)
```

I couldn't say how efficient this would be, however. I don't believe it should be bad.

A `Counter` has a `dict`-like syntax:

```
>>> count = Counter((x, y) for (x, y, *z) in a)
>>> count['309', '308']
2
```

Edit: You mentioned they might be of any length greater than one, in this case, you could run into problems as they won't be able to unpack if they are shorter than the required length. The solution is to change the generator expression to ignore any not in the required format:

```
Counter((item[0], item[1]) for item in a if len(item) >= 2)
```

E.g:

```
>>> a = ( ('309',), ('309','308','308'), ('309','308','307'), ('308', '309','306', '304'))
>>> Counter((x, y) for (x, y, *z) in a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/collections.py", line 460, in __init__
    self.update(iterable, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/collections.py", line 540, in update
    _count_elements(self, iterable)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <genexpr>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
>>> Counter((item[0], item[1]) for item in a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/collections.py", line 460, in __init__
    self.update(iterable, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/collections.py", line 540, in update
    _count_elements(self, iterable)
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <genexpr>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
>>> Counter((item[0], item[1]) for item in a if len(item) >= 2)
Counter({('309', '308'): 2, ('308', '309'): 1})
```

If you need to have a variable length count, the easiest way is to use a list slice:

```
start = 0
end = 2
Counter(item[start:end] for item in a if len(item) >= start+end)
```

Of course, this only works for continuous runs, if you want to pick columns individually, you have to do a little more work:

```
def pick(seq, indices):
    return tuple([seq[i] for i in indices])

columns = [1, 3]
maximum = max(columns)
Counter(pick(item, columns) for item in a if len(item) > maximum)
```

Comment: Ok. This concept looks interesting. Never knew it. So, I will be reading in a from a file which has 50000 paths. And, then i'd use the counter concept in a loop to determine. Let me see how I can make it work. But, your help is awesome. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Sagar: I added a note given your point about potentially shorter tuples. If this answers your problem, [feel free to accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: I have a new problem. The item[0], item[1] is variable for me. That is, I need to calculate Counter(item[0], item[1]) first. I do not know the number of item[i] at the time of programming. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Sagar I have added a solution for the more general problem.

Comment: You are awesome! Is there a way I can commend you in this forum?

Comment: @Sagar If you feel my answer is good, simply upvote and/or accept my answer, no need for more than that.

Comment: @Lattyware - just wondering if there is a particular reason why using `Counter` over list comprehensions is favoured for this task, when OP only interested in the count of certain elements, and also its a bit slower, although maybe not a big deal.. (see my timeit comparisons below, unpacking slows things down a surprisingly large amount). Thanks :)

Comment: I thought it was the clearest and most readable option, but yeah, if you are most bothered by performance and only care about one particular thing, then list comps could well be faster.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this in the CS-style efficient way, you should look at [tries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). You'd need a slight modification to store the size of each subtree on its root, but that shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: i did try trie from an efficiency point of view. Actually, radix tree would have been the best. But, I couldnt get much google help on using the python implementation of the packages pytrie and pyradix. So, I failed. If I knew how they would work, I agree they're the optimum soln.

Comment: +1, this is a good solution if you need optimal performance - however it would take a lot more implementing, so if the simple ``Counter`` approach is fast *enough*, that's what counts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are pre-Python 2.7, you could use list comprehensions:

```
#Number of: ('309','308', <any word>)
>>> len([i[0] for i in a if i[0]=='309' and i[1]=='308'])
2
#Number of:('309',<any word>,'308')
>>> len([i[0] for i in a if i[0]=='309' and i[-1]=='308'])
1
```

Using a list comrehension also seems to be somewhat faster than using `Counter`, and although the tuple unpacking is nice, it also slows things downa bit. `defaultdict` can accomplish a similar thing a little bit quicker:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

a = []
for i in range(500000):
    a.append(('309','308','308'))

def ww(a):
    return Counter((item[0], item[1]) for item in a)

def xx(a):
    return len([i[0] for i in a if i[0]=='309' and i[1]=='308'])

def yy(a):
    g = defaultdict(int)
    for i in a:
        g[(i[0],i[1])] += 1
    return g

def zz(a):
    return Counter((i, j) for (i, j, *k) in a)

from timeit import timeit
print('Counter..:',timeit("ww(a)", "from __main__ import ww, a", number=100))
print('compreh..:',timeit("xx(a)", "from __main__ import xx, a", number=100))
print('defdict..:',timeit("yy(a)", "from __main__ import yy, a", number=100))
print('Count+un.:',timeit("zz(a)", "from __main__ import zz, a", number=100))
#output:
Counter..: 8.411258935928345
compreh..: 2.8653810024261475
defdict..: 4.256785154342651
Count+un.: 18.45333218574524
```